# Error on angular 7 on shared web + mobile project

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular7

after `ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics project-name --share` ng serve working fine for web but for android mobile its failing with below error.

on `tns run andorid --bundle` getting below error.

```
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.mmapp on device emulator-5554.
JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6
System.err:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2101)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1139)
System.err:     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:107)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1102)
```

Comment: What do you have in your `app.component[.tns].html`

Comment: I have not edited any single line its just default code by ng new

Comment: in app.component[.tns].html is <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>

Comment: Do you have a repo where I can see the code & issue?

Comment: just run ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics project-name --share  you will get the code

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `tns doctor` issue with android sdk older version is resolved now.